# Python v3 Checkbutton, checked, not checked value (i in range list)

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Currently I have a gui tkinter window working for some Radiobuttons. These radio buttons are displayed in the window by a list (i for range) and can each be checked only once, 1 to many. Basically the radio buttons are working fine.

I also want to achieve the same result, except with check buttons. So I can select mutiple options at once, meaning either having 1 to many or many to many.

I have the value as value = i for the radio buttons, however I am not sure how to do this with the checkbuttons. I know that they require a different sort of function for values.

My code is as follows:

Lists:

```
    breads = ["White", "Wheat"] #"Multigrain" - Can be added to list to see GUI respond to new ingredients
    cheeses = ["Swiss", "Cheddar"] #Edam - Can be added...
    salads = ["Lettuce", "Tomato"] #Capsicum, Cucumber - Can be added...
    meats = ["Bacon", "Salami"] # Bacon - Can be added...
    sauces = ["Mayo"] #Honey Mustard - Can be added...
```

Labels and buttons:

```
    Label(self,
          text = "Bread Type ($2):",
          ).grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.breads_btns = []
    for i in range(len(breads)):
        rb = Radiobutton(self, variable = self.breads_var, value = i, anchor = W, text = breads[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.breads_btns.append(rb)
        rb.grid(row =(i + 11), column = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(self,
          text = "Cheeses ($1):",
          ).grid(row = 22, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.cheeses_btns = []
    for i in range(len(cheeses)):
        rb = Radiobutton(self, variable = self.cheeses_var, value = i, anchor = W, text = cheeses[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.cheeses_btns.append(rb)
        rb.grid(row =(i + 23), column = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(self,
          text = "Salads ($2):",
          ).grid(row = 33, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.salads_btns = []
    for i in range(len(salads)):
        cb = Checkbutton(self, variable = self.salads_var, anchor = W, text = salads[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.salads_btns.append(cb)
        cb.grid(row =(i + 34), column = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(self,
          text = "Meats ($4):",
          ).grid(row = 44, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.meats_btns = []
    for i in range(len(meats)):
        cb = Checkbutton(self, variable = self.meats_var, anchor = W, text = meats[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.meats_btns.append(cb)
        cb.grid(row =(i + 45), column = 0, sticky = W)

    Label(self, 
          text = "Sauces ($1):",
          ).grid(row = 55, column = 0, sticky = W) 

    self.sauces_btns = []
    for i in range(len(sauces)):
        rb = Radiobutton(self, variable = self.sauces_var, value = i, anchor = W, text = sauces[i], command=self.show_sentence)
        self.sauces_btns.append(rb)
        rb.grid(row =(i + 56), column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Output:
[Image of Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAV8A.png)

Overall can anyone help me with the functions I need for the values for checkbuttons. Also I need them to be able to be displayed in a text box, when checked (future code I plan to implement).

Comment: Checkbuttons each require their own `StringVar` instance.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the variable equal to a stringvar. I'm not sure though how to get the value's working with this for 'i range'. i.e what would I use for the onvalue and offvalue?